# Server Error in Application, Hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, web-deployment-project

Here is the detailed error:

[image: Boom]

The project works on my local computer. i am using publish to a file folder and moving the files to the server. When trying to go to the website i get the error provided in the image url.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a corrupt sitemap xml file containing null bytes. So as the error message suggests look at the first character of line 215 of your XML file in a hex editor and compare with the *working* version you have in your development environment in order to try to identify the differences.